# Can Blender create a curved surface from vertices and a custom formula?

Tags: bezier-curves, customization, mathematics, smooth, nurbs-surface

Is it possible to use blender to create a curved surface based on an original formula instead of the one used to create NURBS?

The way curved surfaces are created by computers is, for each conceivable point on a rectilinear surface, a formula is applied which evaluates the position of control vertices to determine where in space that location on the surface should be. What I'm wondering is, if it's possible to use a unique formula to evaluate the vertices, there in producing a new form which could be drastically different than would be the NURBS surface produced by those same control vertices?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271855/how-do-i-render-the-implicit-function-z2-x-y-1z-y-0-in-blender/272055#272055) and [that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270409/how-can-i-plot-this-cartesian-equation-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: Here's another one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271833/how-to-render-y-x-1-y-x12-4y-1-2-2-in-blender